# should I build llvm for iphone-dev on ubuntu?

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, llvm

I try to follow this guide:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building

it wants me to build **LLVM** from source, but I already have one installed in **Ubuntu** using **apt-get**, why they want me to compile from source? can I use the one provided by **Ubuntu** community? if not, how will they coexist? should I uninstall apt-installed **llvm** first?

Answer (score 3):

The guide you're looking at is several years out of date, and will most likely **not** work. (In fact, there are a ton of frustrated comments suggesting that it hasn't worked since at least 2011, as the Mac OS X 10.4u SDK is no longer available for download.)

The only supported platform for iOS development is Mac OS X. I would strongly recommend that you use that platform if you want to do iOS development, as basically all tutorials you will find online will assume that's what you're using.

That all being said, **if** the instructions were otherwise correct, you would still need to build LLVM separately from the version provided by Ubuntu, as iOS devices use ARM CPUs, and the distribution's LLVM will only compile binaries for your system (probably either x86 or x86-64).

Comment: Well, it's true. Even *if* exebook does manage to get an application built and working on an iOS device -- which will be extremely difficult using that toolchain -- it will be entirely impossible to make it available on the App Store.